# Reading CrystalReport's Field Value Programmatically

Tags: c#, .net, crystal-reports

I'm using C#.NET to programmatically load a Crystal Report document (which gets its data from a database) and then export it as a PDF.

I'm stuck trying to read a fields (abc123) value from within the report (I want to use it in the filename).  I don't mind where this field is in the crystal report; and it will not be repeated, but it needs to be a field in the report.

My code so far:

```
// Setup
ReportDocument reportTemplate = new ReportDocument();
reportTemplate.Load(textBox1.Text);
reportTemplate.Refresh();
reportTemplate.ReadRecords();

// Load the current reports name from the report summary information
String ReportName = reportTemplate.SummaryInfo.ReportTitle.ToString();

// Load the current reports "abc123" field from the report
// ????

// Export the report as PDF
reportTemplate.Export();
```

I've tried:

```
// Load the current reports "abc123" field from the report
String abcField = ((TextObject)rpt.Section2.ReportObjects["abc123"]).Text
String abcField = reportTemplate.ReportDefinition.ReportObjects["abc123"].ToString();
String abcField = reportTemplate.Rows.ReportDocument.ReportDefinition.ReportObjects["abc123"];
```

Without luck. Can anyone give some pointers? I can preview the report using crystalReportView1 object and the field is populated there.

Comment: Why do you need to do this?
You've already have data object to show in report, so why don't you get this field from data object instead?

Comment: It's a field calculated within the report, different reports have different calculations...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you will not be able to pull a calculated field value from code behind.  The calculated field value is not available until after the report engine takes over and does the rendering.  You can access/modify formula definitions before the report is rendered but have no access to the actual value calculated from code behind.  Even if you add a blank subreport and add a parameter to it from the main report for the field value you are trying to access it will not have a value before the reports engine renders it.  You should definitely look for a way to pull it from the data you are binding the report with.

Comment: Thanks - I had came to the same conclusion myself.