# Get Included Rows from DataSource after ReadRecords

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

Is it possible to read which records were included in a report after the selection formula is applied via `ReadRecords`?

```
ReportDocument reportDocument = new ReportDocument();
reportDocument.Load(@"report.rpt");

DataSet reportDataSet = new DataSet();
reportDataSet.ReadXml(@"data.xml");

reportDocument.SetDataSource(reportDataSet);
reportDocument.ReadRecords();
```

`reportDocument.Rows.Count` returns the correct number of rows. However, the only column in the `CrystalReportDataRowView` available is "RecordNumber", and not any of the columns provided by the data source.

Answer (score 1):

If you are map physical database object, then you will be get the records count with column value.

But as you are assign xml data, so crystal report will does not give you any thing, because all are runtime set and render by Crystal report.

Please read below link the understand the logic of crystal report with datasource "

[Reading CrystalReport's Field Value Programmically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7508485/reading-crystalreports-field-value-programmically)